# How to disable search in html table using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

[html table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZTT7.png)

I would like to search using only first column. I have used below code but it didn't workout.

```
"aoColumnDefs": [
      { "bSearchable": true, "aTargets": [ 0 ] },
      { "bSearchable": false, "aTargets": [ 1] },
      { "bSearchable": false, "aTargets": [ 2] },
      { "bSearchable": false, "aTargets": [ 3] }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use DataTables.js?

If it's true, you can define searchable of columns like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": [ 2 ],
                "searchable": false
            },
            {
                "targets": [ 3 ],
                "searchable": true
            }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

I suggest you read [the manual of DataTables.js](https://datatables.net/examples/index)

Comment: Maybe you should use "aoColumns" insted of "aoColumnDefs"

Comment: tried with aoColumns also still issue not resolved. is there any dependency  with Jquery versions?